# Order of writing to an HTML file

Tags: c++, logging, fstream

Ok, the title is probably confusing (but I couldn't come up with a better one) - I've created a simple Logger class that outputs to an HTML file. The file has some stuff at the top (title, js/css includes, etc...), some code at the end and of course variable-length content (actual logs) in the middle. I also want to use a combobox whose content also depends on the logs.

So the problem is - how do I create the begging and end of the file at my Logger's `init()` and then start writing in the middle of the file (actually in 2 different places) throughout the execution of the application (collecting and writing logs)? There probably is a way to start writing in an arbitrary place in the file (and not at the end) but I'm also very concerned with performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you cannot write to the middle of a file without rewriting the whole thing. And the idea of using an XML (or HTML) format as the first sink of your log is probably not the best one.

Maybe you can consider a format where you can simply append the next log message (like a database, or a plain file where you simply `write(str)` to the open file handle), and then write the XML (or HTML) on demand. You could even create a rotating logger, where every `N` messages you dump the corresponding HTML, and carry on.